# Is is possible for a Compact Framework 2.0 App to consume a WCF Web service

Tags: vb.net, wcf, compact-framework, compact-framework2.0

We are in the process of creating a new WCF web service (WCF service that has an basicHttpBinding Endpoint)  to carry out some of our business logic.

The web application connects not problem at all, however our legacy Compact framework application doesn't seem to see the service at all.

Are we on to a loser here and should we just revert to ASMX web service (the Compact framework cannot be upgraded) or is there a way around this?

Comment: CF only supports a subset of things that WCF can offer. Check out this post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewarnottms/archive/2007/08/21/the-wcf-subset-supported-by-netcf.aspx

Comment: I think that is using Compact 3.5, as Compact WCF is only available in that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but you need to treat it as a soap service not a WCF service with all the .net 3.5 goodness. Start up your web service and create web service reference in your .net 2.0 CF and use the auto generated code.